# Densheilds project progress with leveling issue

Tags: tile, support, gap, leveling, backer-board

I  have installed Densheilds tile backer boards as showed in the pictures and I noticed on the big board (5'x5') that at the corner there is a light gap (*not leveled.*) I'm going to install a 12"X24" porcelain tile on it.

Will this slight gap  be an issue when I start tiling or can it be leveled with adding more thinset in this area.

[image]!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKd6U.jpg)[image]

Comment: I do not understand what the relationship is between the wood and the denshield. Why are the two meeting and where? The close up photos provide no context and the wide photo does not show the 2x4 or whatever the wood is.

Comment: Sorry..The wood is not related to anything..I just use it to show the gap (non levelness).so if I started tiling from left to right at the right area where is the red marking in the picture this side will not be leveled..the densheild is curving little bit that you csnt see with your eyes..I think the stud in the right corner was inside more than the others..